# list of items only filling first one

Tags: android

I created a custom adapter to fill the item i have depending on how many elements there is but it only fills the first item and i can't figure out why

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/customList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_text_2"
    android:layout_width="116dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:text="Default Text 2"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_below="@+id/item_text_1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_text_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:text="Default Text 1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_text_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:text="Default Text 3"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp" />
```

**Custom Class**

```
public class CustomClass {
    private String txt1, txt2, txt3;
public CustomClass(String txt1, String txt2, String txt3) {
    this.txt1 = txt1;
    this.txt2 = txt2;
    this.txt3 = txt3;
}

public String getTxt1() {
    return txt1;
}

public String getTxt2() {
    return txt2;
}

public String getTxt3() {
    return txt3;
}
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<CustomClass> lst_stuff = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    populateCustomClass();
    populateListView();
}

private void populateCustomClass()
{
    lst_stuff.add(new CustomClass("First", "I Got", "FIRST!!!!!"));
    lst_stuff.add(new CustomClass("Second", "How did you...", "you know what GG"));
    lst_stuff.add(new CustomClass("Third", "I Got", "Last?!! ... I am just too good to be first"));
}

private void populateListView()
{
    ArrayAdapter<CustomClass> adapter = new CustomAdapter();
    ListView lst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.customList);
    lst.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomClass>
{
    public CustomAdapter()
    {
        super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item, lst_stuff);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View itemView = convertView;

        if (itemView == null)
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

        try 
        {
            CustomClass customClass = lst_stuff.get(position);

            TextView textView_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_text_1);
            textView_1.setText(customClass.getTxt1());

            TextView textView_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_text_2);
            textView_2.setText(customClass.getTxt2());

            TextView textView_3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_text_3);
            textView_3.setText(customClass.getTxt3());
        }
        catch (NullPointerException exception)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        return itemView;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

is there something missing or something doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if your remove 
if (itemView == null)

Comment: if i remove item view == null it will crash causing null pointer exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All seems to be ok, but I would change what is on the method getView() by this:

```
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.
           getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

    CustomClass customClass = lst_stuff.get(position);

    ((TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_text_1)).
          setText(customClass.getTxt1());
    ((TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_text_2)).
          setText(customClass.getTxt2());
    ((TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_text_3)).
          setText(customClass.getTxt3());

    return rowView;
  }
```

I think that you must obtain first a instance of inflater, and then inflate your view (rowView) with your layout (R.layout.item).

Good luck!

Comment: I did but nothing changed, my exact problem is me having a list containing x number of elements = to lst nb of elements but, beside the 1st item, the others contain default values

Comment: I understand. I think that you have to relate your view with textviews. Like this: `TextView textView_1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_text_1);` So associate each TextView to the view (itemView) that you are filling.

Comment: i did that in the custom adapter class it fills only one item if you want i can link you a screenshot of the result